# How to find particular value in JSON and display the minimum of those values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, hashset

I am new to JS and trying to work on a task and not find an exact solution for the same.
This is the first time I am posting questions so please correct me wherever I am going wrong.

Here is my question

This is a small part of my JSON file  which is more than 3000 lines for which I have given the exact format of the same JSON file

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M1",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m1",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1 status",
          "instance": "m1.e1.s1",
          "job": "m1",
          "src": "m1.m1.m1",
          "src_vm": "m1",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "100"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M2",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m2",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1.e1",
          "instance": "m2",
          "job": "m2 services",
          "src": "m2.m3",
          "src_vm": "m2",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "99.919094"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M2",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m2",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1.e1",
          "instance": "m2",
          "job": "m2 services",
          "src": "m2.m3",
          "src_vm": "m2",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "98.406375"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M1",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m1",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1 status",
          "instance": "m1.e1.s1",
          "job": "m1",
          "src": "m1.m1.m1",
          "src_vm": "m1",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "100"
        ]
      }
}
```

My question is how can I check the complete JSON file and search for the cloud key and its values and display the minimum of the value.

For example
I have to fetch the cloud with the name M1 in the whole JSON which may occur around 12 times.

"cloud": "m2",
"cloud_kpi": "m1.e1"

in the above line, my required key will be cloud and the value will be m2.
after this i have to fetch the value of this cloud that is,

"value": [
1653633595.484,
"100"
]

here the value I need is 100.

in the same way, I have to check for these values in a complete JSON file and get around 12 values

m1-100
m1-100
m2-33
m1-44 .......so on

after getting these values I need to find minimum of these and display them.

In the same way, I have to fetch all the cloud's and its minimum  value that is
M1-min(100,98,94...)
M2-min(100,38,99,...)
M3-min(100,39,20..)
and so on....

I tried the map method which was confusing for me and also for each method at last I was just able to fetch all cloud names but not move further

```
response.json().then(function (data) {
                        var jsonarray = data["data"]["result"]                    
                        for (var k in jsonarray) {
                            if (jsonarray[k] instanceof Object) {
                                console.log(jsonarray[k].metric.cloud)                                                
                            } 
                        }
                    });
```

Please let me know what is the next step I have to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the objects where the cloud id matches the query.
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that array to return only the value you need.
3. From *that* array find the minimum value using [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

```js
const data={status:"success",data:{resultType:"vector",result:[{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M1",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m1",cloud_kpi:"m1 status",instance:"m1.e1.s1",job:"m1",src:"m1.m1.m1",src_vm:"m1",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"100"]},{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M2",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m2",cloud_kpi:"m1.e1",instance:"m2",job:"m2 services",src:"m2.m3",src_vm:"m2",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"99.919094"]},{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M2",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m2",cloud_kpi:"m1.e1",instance:"m2",job:"m2 services",src:"m2.m3",src_vm:"m2",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"98.406375"]},{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M1",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m1",cloud_kpi:"m1 status",instance:"m1.e1.s1",job:"m1",src:"m1.m1.m1",src_vm:"m1",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"999"]}]}};

function findMinimum(data, key) {

  // `filter` out the objects where the value
  // of `cloud` matches your query
  const result = data.data.result.filter(obj => {
    return obj.metric.cloud?.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase();

  // For each object return the second element
  // of the value array
  }).map(obj => {
    return obj.value[1];
  });

  // `spread` out the array and use `Math.min` to
  // find the minimum value
  return Math.min(...result);

}

console.log(`Minimum value: ${findMinimum(data, 'M1')}`);
```

Additional documentation

- [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Please, check following code:

```
const data = response.json();
const result = data.data.result;

// mapping
const mappedArray = result.map(x => ({
    cloud: x.metric.cloud,
    value: Number(x.value[1] ?? 0)
}))
const maxSorted = mappedArray.sort((x, y) => y.value - x.value) // sorting
const minSorted = mappedArray.sort((x, y) => x.value - y.value) 
const maxValue = maxSorted[0] ?? null;
const minValue = minSorted[0] ?? null;
console.log(maxValue); // max value
console.log(minValue); // min value
```

Short styled:

```
response.json().then((data) => {
    const minValue = data.data.result.map(x => ({
        cloud: x.metric.cloud,
        value: Number(x.value[1] ?? 0)
    })).sort((x, y) => x.value - y.value)
    console.log(minValue)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter()` to find value of an array and `Math.min()` to find minimum value of its parameters

```js
response.json().then(function(data){
    var jsonarray = data.data.result.filter(item => item.metric.cloud == 'm2') // here you will have all of the objects with the cloud m2
    const min = Math.min(...jsonarray.map(item => item.value[1]))
    console.log(min) // the minimum value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to print minimum value among all the objects that you have in the array. You can simply get all the values in a seperate array and then using `Math.min(...array)` you can fetch the miminum value.

Demo **:**

```js
const obj = {
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M1",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m1",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1 status",
          "instance": "m1.e1.s1",
          "job": "m1",
          "src": "m1.m1.m1",
          "src_vm": "m1",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "100"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M2",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m2",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1.e1",
          "instance": "m2",
          "job": "m2 services",
          "src": "m2.m3",
          "src_vm": "m2",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "99.919094"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M2",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m2",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1.e1",
          "instance": "m2",
          "job": "m2 services",
          "src": "m2.m3",
          "src_vm": "m2",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "98.406375"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M1",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m1",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1 status",
          "instance": "m1.e1.s1",
          "job": "m1",
          "src": "m1.m1.m1",
          "src_vm": "m1",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "100"
        ]
      }]
  }
};

const values = [];

obj.data.result.forEach(obj => {
    obj.value.forEach(value => {
    values.push(Math.round(value))
  });
});

console.log(Math.min(...values));
```