# How to pass array resulting from for loop to the function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, for-loop

I am new to programming and stuck in an issue. It might be a silly doubt but I cannont proceed further.

Below is my JSON file

```
  {
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M1",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m1",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1 status",
          "instance": "m1.e1.s1",
          "job": "m1",
          "src": "m1.m1.m1",
          "src_vm": "m1",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "100"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M2",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m2",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1.e1",
          "instance": "m2",
          "job": "m2 services",
          "src": "m2.m3",
          "src_vm": "m2",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "99.919094"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M2",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m2",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1.e1",
          "instance": "m2",
          "job": "m2 services",
          "src": "m2.m3",
          "src_vm": "m2",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "98.406375"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "ABC": "yes",
          "KPI": "M1",
          "__name__": "m1_status",
          "cloud": "m1",
          "cloud_kpi": "m1 status",
          "instance": "m1.e1.s1",
          "job": "m1",
          "src": "m1.m1.m1",
          "src_vm": "m1",
          "timespan": "2h"
        },
        "value": [
          1653633595.484,
          "100"
        ]
      }
}
```

I need to pass the values of the cloud from for loop to an array and then function getUnique. Below is my code structure.

```
response.json().then(function (data) {
var jsonarray = data["data"]["result"]
                        for (i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i++) {
                            var names = data["data"]["result"][i]["metric"]["cloud"]
                            var new = []
                            new.push(names)
                            console.log(new)
                        }
                        
                        
                        function getUnique(array) {
                            var uniqueArray = [];

                            // Loop through array values
                            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                if (uniqueArray.indexOf(array[i]) === -1) {
                                    uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            return uniqueArray;
                        }
                        var uniqueNames = getUnique(new);
                        console.log(uniqueNames);


}
```

The above for the loop is fetching the cloud value and then pushing the value to a new array and the function getunique is deleting the duplicate items from the array passed and returning the unique items .

My problem here is, that I am able to pass a sample array with hardcoded values but not able to pass an array from the JSON file which is the cloud name.

The final result I need is an array of unique cloud names. in my JSON result will be [m1,m1].

I tried writing a function above the for loop but again that did not work. please suggest me what I am missing here.

Comment: If you redeclare `var new = []` in each iteration, it will be always cleaned. Declare it outside the loop.

Comment: And your data is not valid which is why you may have problems. There are some missing `]` and `}`.

Comment: @andy Thank you. Actually, the data I am taking is from the API not hardcoded so that might not be an issue. I just need to pass the resulting cloud name to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data set to get an array of clouds, and then use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to dedupe that array of elements. Finally use the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to return the set to an array you can log.

```js
const data={status:"success",data:{resultType:"vector",result:[{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M1",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m1",cloud_kpi:"m1 status",instance:"m1.e1.s1",job:"m1",src:"m1.m1.m1",src_vm:"m1",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"100"]},{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M2",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m2",cloud_kpi:"m1.e1",instance:"m2",job:"m2 services",src:"m2.m3",src_vm:"m2",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"99.919094"]},{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M2",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m2",cloud_kpi:"m1.e1",instance:"m2",job:"m2 services",src:"m2.m3",src_vm:"m2",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"98.406375"]},{metric:{ABC:"yes",KPI:"M1",__name__:"m1_status",cloud:"m1",cloud_kpi:"m1 status",instance:"m1.e1.s1",job:"m1",src:"m1.m1.m1",src_vm:"m1",timespan:"2h"},value:[1653633595.484,"100"]}]}};

const clouds = data.data.result.map(obj => {
  return obj.metric.cloud;
});

console.log(...new Set(clouds));
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy this is working for me. Getting clouds in an array. Can you please suggest to me how can I pass this to a function? I am using a map for this but the value is not being passed. const                                                                                                              
                         newArr = clouds.map(cloud=>{
                            findMinimum(data,cloud)
                        });
                        console.log(newArr)

Comment: This is the same issue that I had posted earlier  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72514765/how-to-find-particular-value-in-json-and-display-the-minimum-of-those-values-in